# Text and Image Alignment Issue Minipage Environment

Tags: minipage, alignment

I have been looking on the exchange to solve this issue and without much success. I am using trial and error to align my figure and text and can't get them to be the same height.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}                  
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphics,graphicx}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
 

        
\pgfplotsset{my style polar/.append style={xticklabels={,,
$\frac{\pi}{6}$, $\frac{\pi}{3}$, $\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\frac{2\pi}{3}$,
$\frac{5\pi}{6}$, $\pi$, $\frac{7\pi}{6}$, $\frac{4\pi}{3}$,
$\frac{3\pi}{2}$, $\frac{5\pi}{3}$,$\frac{11\pi}{6}$,}, thick }}

                        % Activate to display a given date or no dat
\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\begin{minipage}[t]{8cm}
    \question Given a point with rectangular coordinates $\big(-3,3\sqrt{3}\big)$ find a polar coordinate where $r<0$ and $0\leq \theta<2\pi$ \textbf{use exact answer for $\theta$}.
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{5cm}
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{/Users/nbennett/Dropbox/Mathematics/Courses/2021-2022/PCH/Unit 8/Assessment/graph1.png}
\end{minipage}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thank you for any help

Comment: Is https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ev9ru.png the output you're trying to achieve?

Comment: along with the text in \question.  I just can't seem to align them now matter what adjustments I make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure If I understood your alignment requirements correctly, but here is are two example on how you could align the first line of the question text with the top of the image. In both examples, I used the `valign=t` option provided when adding `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` to the preamble:

Red lines indicate margins:

[image]

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphics,graphicx}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
 \usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % <----- added in order to provide the valign option used below

        
\pgfplotsset{my style polar/.append style={xticklabels={,,
$\frac{\pi}{6}$, $\frac{\pi}{3}$, $\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\frac{2\pi}{3}$,
$\frac{5\pi}{6}$, $\pi$, $\frac{7\pi}{6}$, $\frac{4\pi}{3}$,
$\frac{3\pi}{2}$, $\frac{5\pi}{3}$,$\frac{11\pi}{6}$,}, thick }}

                        % Activate to display a given date or no dat


\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\begin{minipage}[t]{8cm}
    \question Given a point with rectangular coordinates $(-3,3\sqrt{3})$ find a polar coordinate where $r<0$ and $0\leq \theta<2\pi$ \textbf{use exact answer for $\theta$}.
\end{minipage}
\quad % <------ added for a small additional amount of horizontal space between question and image
\includegraphics[scale=.5,valign=t]{example-image} % <------ added valign=t, rmoved surrounding minipage environment
\end{questions}


\begin{questions}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-5cm-2em}
    \question Given a point with rectangular coordinates $(-3,3\sqrt{3})$ find a polar coordinate where $r<0$ and $0\leq \theta<2\pi$ \textbf{use exact answer for $\theta$}.
\end{minipage}
\hfill 
\includegraphics[width=5cm,valign=t]{example-image} % <------ added valign=t
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Either would work. Thank you so much!